# How to setup a modal popup login form when click on login rather rendiring into a login page

Tags: magento2, modal-popup, modal, login-register

I am new to magento2. I want a pop login form modal when I click on the login button.
please help in achieving it.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.siphor.com/add-a-login-popup-in-magento-2/ This link will help you to create a module

you can override the authentication-popup.js within your theme to include an additional class that triggers the popup.